# How to loop an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

data is here
subprojects={"RFv6bJMG2dmiBqWNZX8O":{"content":"this is ・・data"}}

```
console.log("subprojects=" + JSON.stringify(subprojects));
```

```
const SubList = ({ subprojects }) => {
if(subprojects){
  return (
    <div className="project-list section">
      {subprojects &&
        subprojects.map((subproject) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {subproject.id}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );}
  else{
```

The result is
TypeError: subprojects.map is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 3):

use Object.entries. Check [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
      {
        Object.entries(subprojects).map(([key, val]) => {
          return (
            <div key={key}>
              {val.id}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Alternatively you can also use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) if you are not concerned about the keys